# incompatible types: java.lang.object cannot be converted to java.util.map.entry

Tags: java

Why am i getting the error mentioned on line 27?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class JSONObject {
    private static final Double NEGATIVE_ZERO = -0.0;
    public static final Object NULL = new Object(){

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return o == this || o == null;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "null";
        }
    };
    private final Map<String, Object> nameValuePairs;

    public JSONObject() {
        this.nameValuePairs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public JSONObject(Map copyFrom) {
        this();
        Map contentsTyped = copyFrom;
        for (Map.Entry entry : contentsTyped.entrySet()) {
            String key = (String)entry.getKey();
            if (key == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            this.nameValuePairs.put(key, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

it has to do with the type of the variable contentsTyped but i dont know why and how to change it

Comment: What is the type of copyFrom and contentsTyped.entrySet() in your debugger?

Comment: im using recaf to export the code with only a string or two changed, but even though it worked for the first time, now it doesnt

Comment: If you use a framework to load the object? it will use reflection to invoke the constructor and thus circumvent the type checks. What do you try to achieve here exactly?

Comment: would it be easier if i were to send you the full code?

Comment: Side note: implementing `equals` as `return o == this || o == null;` violates the symmetry requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the raw type of "Map" in the constructor. It is considered as an object type. You created the below variable including parameter type.

```
private final Map<String, Object> nameValuePairs;
```

You have to use the same parameter typed map object in the constructor to resolve this issue, the updated code will be like that:

```
public JSONObject(Map<String, Object> copyFrom) {
    this();
    Map<String, Object> contentsTyped = copyFrom;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : contentsTyped.entrySet()) {
        String key = (String)entry.getKey();
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.nameValuePairs.put(key, entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

It will work correctly in this way.

Comment: When you add the type parameters, you can omit the type cast, i.e. write `String key = entry.getKey();` instead `String key = (String)entry.getKey();` And the code becomes much simpler when omitting the obsolete second variable holding the same map. Or simplify the entire constructor to `public JSONObject(Map<String, Object> copyFrom) { this.nameValuePairs = new HashMap<>(copyFrom); if(this.nameValuePairs.containsKey(null)) throw new NullPointerException(); }`

Comment: Yes, you are right on optimizing the code. I was just trying to inform him about the issue faced by him.